# Replace html entity if within curly braces

Tags: html, regex, replace

I have this string below. I can capture each curly brace with `(\{\{.*?\}\})/igm` but I need a way of replacing any instance of `&#x27;` with `"` in the below string, with javascript.

```
{% layout none %}<html data-reactid=".1h8va4op8n4" data-react-checksum="-832592417">
  <head lang="en" data-reactid=".1h8va4op8n4.0">
     <meta charset="UTF-8" data-reactid=".1h8va4op8n4.0.0">
     <title data-reactid=".1h8va4op8n4.0.1"></title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ &#x27;main.css&#x27; | asset_file }}" data-reactid=".1h8va4op8n4.0.2">
  </head>
  <body data-reactid=".1h8va4op8n4.1">
     <div id="main" data-reactid=".1h8va4op8n4.1.0"></div>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ &#x27;bundle.js&#x27; | asset_file }}" data-reactid=".1h8va4op8n4.1.1"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using a callback function.

```
var r = s.replace(/{{[^}]*}}/g, function(v) { 
      return v.replace(/&#x27;/g, '"');
});
```